# How do I combine the %pylab and %run magic commands in IPython?

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am having trouble using pylab in a .py file that I am using the %run command on in IPython.

If I use the IPython interpreter and type

```
%pylab
plot([1,2,3])
```

A graph appears, but if I save a file plotting.py with the text

```
plot([1,2,3])
```

then use the IPython interpreter and type

%pylab
%run plotting.py

I get NameError: name 'plot' is not defined. Is there any way for the file I'm using the %run command on to see the namespaces in my IPython interpreter? Alternatively, is there an easy way to duplicate the %pylab magic function in a .py file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `-i` flag to run in the IPython namespace instead of an empty one:

```
%run -i plotting.py
```

See [here](http://ipython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-run) for other useful flags which you can use.